# Скажите, в коде ошибка?Я голову сломал.Вечно пишет ошибку "use of undeclared identifier 'secretNumber

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
cout << "\n               Welcome " << endl;
cout << "\n         to the guess game! \n\n" << endl;
cout << "               Rules\n\n" << endl;
cout << "You write value at 1 before 100,but computer try to guess your value.\n" << endl;
cout << "             Have luck!" << endl;
do
{
srand (static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
int guess=rand() % 100 + 1;
cout << "Enter your value: " << endl;
unsigned int secretNumber; 
cin >> secretNumber;   
if (secretNumber > guess)
{
cout << secretNumber << " is bigger than " << guess << endl;
}
else if (secretNumber < guess)
{
cout << secretNumber << " is littler than " << guess << endl;
}
else
{
cout << "Computer right!\n" << endl;
cout << "Your value: " << secretNumber << endl;
}
} while(secretNumber!=guess);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отформатируем слегка код:

```
do
{
    ......
    unsigned int secretNumber;
    cin >> secretNumber;
    ......
} while(secretNumber!=guess);
```

Вы объявили переменную `secretNumber` в блоке, так что она за его пределами — после закрывающей блок скобки `}` — не видна.

Все правильно...

P.S. К вашему "*is littler than*"... См. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less

Comment: А можете ли вы сказать что мне сделать для решения?

Comment: Вынести объявление переменной за блок, например, перед `do {`.